# Add class to element with ng-class when checkbox inside it is checked

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular-ngmodel

I have a selection of divs with a checkbox each. I'm trying to add a class to the label when each particular checkbox is checked.

I saw I could do it creating a specific model for each box (ng-model:"isChecked-1" and then ng-class="'active' : isChecked-1") and so on, but it doesn't seem very code-efficient.

Any thoughts?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox-inline btn col-md-12" ng-class="{'active' : isChecked}">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" ng-model="isChecked"> Clothes
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox-inline btn col-md-12" ng-class="{'active' : isChecked}">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option2"> Cars
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox-inline btn col-md-12" ng-class="{'active' : isChecked}">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option3"> Music
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the job for a directive:

```
.directive('myCheckbox', function() {

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="col-md-4"> \
                      <label class="checkbox-inline btn col-md-12" ng-class="{active : isChecked}"> \
                         <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" ng-model="isChecked" />{{text}} \
                      </label> \
                   </div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

View:

```
<my-checkbox text='Clothes'></my-checkbox>
<my-checkbox text='Cars'></my-checkbox>
<my-checkbox text='Music'></my-checkbox>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/U3pVM/3240/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!! How do I add a new directive? I tried copying and pasting right afterwards, and changing myCheckbox to another name, but it crashes my code...

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle which shows how to define a directive.

Comment: I cheked it, copied from line 6 to 20 and pasted under it, and changed the directive name. But when I run it it crashes the code. What am I missing?

Comment: It just doesnt render anything on the output.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF5h5/).
I didn't know how to do what you did, and id like to implement it in more places...

Comment: You had a ; after the first directive. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/JF5h5/1/)